# Selenium how to select an object by class

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have a web page with a form and has a field that uses the jquery autocomplete function.

[image]

This is how the HTML renders after a user name returns 1 or more results.

However I cannot figure out how to make Selenium "click" a  result.

[image]

Can I do a jQuery type of selector.
e.g.

```
$(".ul.ui-autocomplete li:first a")
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use XPath selector in Selenium:

```
xpath=//li[contains(@class, 'ui-autocomplete')]/li[1]/a
```

not checked, might require some corrections.

Comment: Hey Tomasz do I put this directly into the "Target" field? 
Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: Yes, it should work. Please take a look at *Element Locators* chapter in: http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0.1/reference.html

Comment: The Selenium reference page @Tomasz indicated is a good starting point, but for a comprehensive cookbook of many commonly used XPath, CSS, and DOM recipes for use with Selenium, see my just-published [Rosetta Stone and Cookbook](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/xpath,-css,-dom-and-selenium-the-rosetta-stone/) on Simple-talk.com.

Answer (score 3):

in response to "Can I do a jQuery type of selector," jQuery uses CSS selectors. Selenium can also use CSS selectors; just prefix the selector with "css=". so:

```
css=.ul.ui-autocomplete li:first a
```

Comment: This needs more explanation, please.

Answer (score 0):

Next way to use xpath like this

```
xpath=/html/body/ul[2]/li[1]/a
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a dynamic XPATH then you can point to an element like this

driver.findElement(By.className(""));