# webdriver node js get multile link under class tag

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

how to get multiple link under-class tag,HTML contain multiple multiple class tag="blog-item-wrap" each tag contain tag . need to get all the href links under-clas's tag

```
<div class="blog-item-wrap">
            <a href="https://website.com/data-wrangling-with/" title="Data 
Wrangling with JavaScript">
                        </a>
   </div>
  <div .... >
  <div class="blog-item-wrap">
            <a href="https://website.com/data-wrangling-with/" title="Data 
    Wrangling with JavaScript">
                        </a>
    </div>
     </div>
```

using this and getting error:

> StaleElementReferenceError: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

```
browser.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@class="blog-item-wrap"]/a')).then(res => {  res.getText().then(text => { console.log('text', text); }).catch(err => { console.log('err', err); });
```

Comment: How did you try? Share your code and exception log

Comment: Based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543724/selenium-how-to-select-an-object-by-class you should use XPATH `//div[contains(@class, 'ui-autocomplete')]/a`

Comment: browser.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@class="blog-item-wrap"]/a')).then(res => {
                console.log(res);
                res.getText().then(text => {
                    console.log('text', text);
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log('err', err);
                });

Comment: trying this but getting error UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: StaleElementReferenceError: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page documen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `getAttribute("href")` on all the elements with `driver.findElements(By.xpath('//*[@class="blog-item-wrap"]/a'))`.

Then iterate the list with the `getAttribute("href")`.

you should think about using `async`...

Hope this helps you!

Comment: bro i am new can u please explain me in code format

Comment: browser.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@class="blog-item-wrap"]//a')).then(res => { res.getAttribute("href")
                .then(text => {
                    console.log('text: ', text)
                })                                                                                                                this give me one link can u please tell how to get all links Thanks

Comment: Just change `browser.findElement` to `browser.findElements`

Answer (score 1):

The error come because the element removed or modified from the page try using `Promise` and use `findElements()` to get all elements.

```
browser.get('https://..........')
.then(() => {
  browser.findElements(By.xpath('//*[@class="blog-item-wrap"]//a'))
  .then(res => {
    var links = res.map(aTags => aTags.getText()) // .getAttribute("href")
    Promise.all(links).then(texts => {
      texts.forEach(text => console.log('text: ', text))
    })
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('err: ', err);
  });
})
```

Non `Promise`

```
browser.get('https://....')
  .then(() => {
    browser.findElements(By.xpath('//*[@class="blog-item-wrap"]//a'))
    .then(res => {
      res.forEach(aTags => {
        aTags.getText()
        //aTags.getAttribute("href")
        .then(text => console.log('text: ', text))
        .catch(err => console.log('err: ', err))
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: res = WebElement {driver_: thenableWebDriverProxy, id_: Promise}
driver_:thenableWebDriverProxy {session_: Promise, executor_: Executor, fileDetector_: null, …}
id_:Promise { resolved }
should:Proxy
__proto__:Object {constructor: , getDriver: , getId: , …}                                                          res.map is not a function error

Comment: may I know URL of the page

Comment: it work find, except in xpath need to change `/a` to `//a` and make sure you're using latest `chromedriver` and `Chrome`

Comment: using non `Promise` also return expected result, see edited answer. I guess the problem is old version of apps.

Comment: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: res.forEach is not a function

Comment: res is in the form of promise not array

Comment: do you use latest `chromedriver` and `Chrome`? also consider updating `nodejs`

Comment: chromedriver is latest i will update chrome and node

Comment: @AtiqUrRehman so you have followed my suggestion to update Chrome?